# Call function inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, I need to pass them one by one to a function, but I want to give a 1sec pause between each item in the array:

```
async function ChamandoEtiquetas() {
    if(id) {
      if(NumerosEtiquetas) {
        NumerosEtiquetas.forEach(async (Etiqueta) => {
        await  MontagemFiltro(Etiqueta)
        })
      }
    }
 
  }

async function MontagemFiltro(Etiqueta) {
    var CodigoDeBarras = "teste";
           await setFiltro(CodigoDeBarras)
  }
```

I need to do this, because there are 2 functions that are called when changing the "setFiltro", and it takes a few milliseconds. Because of that the function is only doing what it has to do with the last index of the array

Comment: Aside: Maybe a pad function?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Please: `const valor = GuardandoValorCartaoOPMomentaneo.toString(); CodigoDeBarras = valor.padStart(valor.length,'0')`

Comment: I did not know this function, thank you very much for letting me know, I will use it. But that's not the problem

Comment: Duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Do not insert arbitrary waiting periods. Use promises to wait the precise duration necessary for asynchronous tasks to complete.

The following will call `MontagemFiltro`, once for each item in `NumerosEtiquetas`, in rapid succession, and return a promise that will resolve to an array of results when all the asynchronous tasks have completed. Note that this will fail fast if any of the asynchronous calls fails.

```js
function ChamandoEtiquetas(id, NumerosEtiquetas) {
  if(!id || !NumerosEtiquetas) return; // this makes an assumption that ids are strings

  return Promise.all(
    NumerosEtiquetas.map((Etiqueta) => MontagemFiltro(Etiqueta)))    
}

function MontagemFiltro(Etiqueta) {
  var CodigoDeBarras = "teste"
  return setFiltro(CodigoDeBarras)
}

// Usage:
ChamandoEtiquetas(id, NumerosEtiquetas)
  .then((results) => /* do something with the results */ )
```